# Migrating users from Wordpress database to Parse

Tags: oauth, parse-platform, wordpress, openid

A mobile app is being built to replicate the functionality of my Wordpress site with almost 5,000 registered users. The dev team is going to be using Parse for a lot of the back-end stuff like user management and online/offline content sync.

I've done quite a bit of searching but have found little on the topic of migrating your users from the Wordpress database to Parse's. In addition, almost half of the user base registered through Wordpress Social Login. I was curious if anyone else had undertaken such a migration or might have any ideas where might be best to start. I feel like there must be some faster way of doing this than hand-coding a script that somehow scrapes the Wordpress and social-plugin database for user accounts and then gracefully recreates them with the Parse framework.

Thanks in advance!